# small mismatch for C++ pointer to object's property in Matlab mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers, mex

I hope my question is not a duplicate, I did my best to find an answer on the web, but unsuccessful.

I am building the binding between Matlab and my own library coded in C++, so I have a Matlab wrapper class for each C++ class and a mex with which the wrapper class can call the C++ methods and properties.

The object is created as persistent in the mex file and then it is passed to the Matlab wrapper as a `mxUINT64_CLASS` with the following:

```
mxArray* handle  = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxUINT64_CLASS, mxREAL);
*reinterpret_cast<myClass**>(mxGetPr(handle)) = (myClass*)obj;
```

When a method is called the wrapper class passes the handle to the mex file where the original C++ pointer is worked out with the following:

```
template<class T>
T* handleToPtr(const mxArray* handle){
if (mxGetClassID(handle) != mxUINT64_CLASS
        || mxIsComplex(handle) || mxGetM(handle)!=1 || mxGetN(handle)!=1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Parameter is not an ObjectHandle type.");

// We *assume* we can store thermoState pointer in the mxUINT64 of handle
T* obj = *reinterpret_cast<T**>(mxGetPr(handle));

if (!obj) // gross check to see we don't have an invalid pointer
    mexErrMsgTxt("Parameter is NULL. It does not represent an ObjectHandle object.");

return obj;
}
```

where T is the class of the object I am handling.

This strategy worked pretty well for many classes, but now I am having some very weird problems.
For one particular class I am having trouble dereferencing the pointers to the class properties (not any problem accessing its methods).
Here there is an example:

```
myClass* obj = handleToPtr<myClass>(prhs[1]);
std::cout << "obj = " << obj << std::endl;
std::cout << "&obj->Name_ = " << &obj->Name_ << std::endl;
plhs[0] = mxCreateString(obj->Name_.c_str());
```

This will not get me the right value of Name_ but only garbage. The strange thing is that I can instead get the right value using gdb. This indeed is the output I have in gdb:

```
obj = 0x7fffd4f09740
&obj->Name_ = 0x7fffd4f09798
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffe2cae700 (LWP 9695)]

Breakpoint 1, mexFunction (nlhs=1, plhs=0x7fffc88d8980, nrhs=2, prhs=0x7fffc88d8e10) at propModuleMex.cpp:157
157                 plhs[0] = mxCreateString(obj->Name_.c_str());
(gdb) print obj
$1 = (propModule *) 0x7fffd4f09740
(gdb) print &obj->Name_
$2 = (std::string *) 0x7fffd4f09778
(gdb) print obj->Name_
$3 = {static npos = <optimised out>, 
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    _M_p = 0x7fffd4c980f8 "Object Name"}}
```

As you can see the pointer to the object `obj` is the same in gdb and in the actual computation (i.e. printed by `std::cout`), but the pointer to the property is different by the last two digits `xxx98` against `xxx78` and the gdb one seems to be the right one since it can dereference it properly.

This strange phenomenon does not happen for many other classes, moreover it doesn't happen also for this class with another version of my C++ library.
The main difference between what works and what doesn't is that the class I am using here is not a base class, but inherits from other classes. In all the other cases I always use the pointer to the base class (converted to the subclass of interest before and after Matlab conversion). Sincerely I don't believe that this can be the issue.

I hope anybody here can point me to the right direction, I'll let you know if I find out more.

Alessandro

**Edit**
I have tried to use `reinterpret_cast` with the base class, that doesn't solve the problem.
I have also tried to use it with a `void*` pointer: same result.
I have also added a get method for the property `Name_` in my library, but I have got even worst garbage. So it seems that the property `Name_` (and also some others, but not all) has this problem in any case.

Comment: seems like gdb and mex are not seeing the same class definition.

Comment: Well, does your use of `reinterpret_cast` yield well-defined behavior?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean exactly? 
It works perfectly for other classes, and in this case it yields the same pointer seen by gdb.

Comment: @user3528438 how this can be possible? how can I make sure it doesn't happen?

Comment: @alexmogavero  What is the actual type returned  by `mxGetPr(handle));`?  What is the error if you did *not* apply the `reinterpret_cast`, or any other casts?   Second, anything to do with two or more levels of indirection (double star programming) needs to be looked at very carefully.  Many times what looks ok isn't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Here there is the reference page for `mxGetPr` http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html
It is specified that it shouldn't be used for type other than double, I have just tried the other option `mcGetData` but it has the same behaviour.
I am not really following you about the "more level of indirection (double star programming)" can you explain? Thanks

Comment: @alexmogavero Can you post `myClass`?  I believe your problem can be explained in just two or three lines of C++ code, and doesn't really need `MatLab`.  The function you linked to returns a `double *`, so if you pluck that line out of the template code and simply do this: `double d= 0; myClass* obj = *reinterpret_cast<myClass**>(&d);`  the question now becomes whether that line of code causes issues that you're not aware of.

Comment: The approach you are attempting is very similar to what is described in [this submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47536-crobarcro-mcode-cpp-utilities) (also at [GitHub](https://github.com/crobarcro/mcode-cpp-utilities)).  I'm not fond of this approach, and I've developed my own, but perhaps looking at this person's can help you.  In a day or two I'll put my approach in GitHub, but it is completely unlike the one under discussion presently.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `MyClass` is quite complex and result of inheritance from several other classes. Can you specify which aspects of the class you need to know?
I think that if I do what you say I will have a seg fault due to the null pointer. Right?

Comment: @chappjc thank you. I am reviewing the code you cited here. I will check if there is any substantial difference with my approach and then try to implement it.

Comment: @alexmogavero I uploaded my code with a different (and hopefully safer) method for wrapping a class here: https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/tree/master/cppClass
If you have a chance and/or still need a more robust solution, please give it a try and give me any feedback you might have.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I identified the problem that was causing this pointer mismatch. I compiled the mex files with the definition -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG while my C++ library, where the class myClass was defined, was compiled without.
Sorting out this issue the problem appears to be solved.